# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' in kivy .kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

STILL, THIS IS SO ANNOYING, kv-kivy-this-that-error, UHH............
Anyway I don't seem to get kivy, Ok I'm STILL playing around in the .kv file
and annoyingly and sluggishly gave up its 'typical' response

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

I feel dumbfounded what is this,WHY KIVY-anyway i must give something to show what really   Is happening
PYTHON

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
Builder.load_file("my.kv")
class MyLayout(Widget,App):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def clear(self):
        self.ids.n.text = ""
        self.ids.fp.text = ""
        self.ids.d.text = ""
    def writeD(self):
        name = self.ids.n.text
        pizza = self.ids.fp.text
        drinks = self.ids.d.text
        orders = open("order.txt","w")
        orders.write(f"Name: {name}\n")
        orders.write(f"Pizza: {pizza}\n")
        orders.write(f"Drinks: {drinks}")
    def read(self):
        orders = open("order.txt","r")
        orderL = orders.read()
        self.ids.layout.add_widget(Label(text=orderL))
class AwesomeApp(App):
   def build(self):
       return MyLayout()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

Yeah like it is--
.kv

```
<Button>
    font_size:20
<TextInput>
    font_size:20
<Label>
    font_size:20
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        id: "layout"
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width,root.height
        padding:10
        spacing:10
        Label:
            text:"Name"
        TextInput:
            id: n
            multiline:False
        Label:
            text:"Pizza"
        TextInput:
            id: fp
            multiline:False
        Label:
            text:"Drinks"
        TextInput:
            id: d
            multiline:False
        Button:
            text:"Submit"
            on_press:root.writeD()
        Button:
            text:"Clear fields"
            on_press:root.clear()
        Button:
            text:"show orders"
            on_press:root.read()
```

yup an attribute error again
can anyone help.PYTHON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `kv` file, `ids` should not be strings. Try changing:

```
id: "layout"
```

to:

```
id: layout
```